# Render React App from another React APP using the complied JS

Tags: html, reactjs, react-dom

I have 2 react apps, lets say app 1 and app 2 with react version 18, I am creating a global.renderApp function that accepts a version as a string, and renders the App and passes down the version as the prop.

Here is an example of the code in app2.

```
global.renderApp = (version: string | null) => {
  const root =  ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('mount') as HTMLElement
  );
  alert("root created");
  root.render(
    <StrictMode>
      <SampleApp version={version}>
        <App />
      </SampleApp>
    </StrictMode>
  );
};
```

Then this app is build i am able to call the renderApp from the browser console and it completes the function.

Now in app1 I am fetching the compiled HTML and then getting the css and js files and appending it to the dom of the first app, Example code below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApp = async (aws_cf_cd_version:string) => {
      const fetchurl =  'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
      try {
        // const headers = new Headers({'x-aws-cf-cd-version': aws_cf_cd_version});

        const response = await fetch(fetchurl, {
          method: 'GET',
          // headers,
          mode: 'cors',
        });

        // fetch the html from the url
        const html = await response.text();
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

        // get all the script and link tags from the html
        const jsFiles = Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll('script')).map(
          ({ src }) => src
        );
        const cssFiles = Array.from(
          doc.querySelectorAll<HTMLLinkElement>('link[rel="stylesheet"]')
        ).map(({ href }) => href);

        // append the script and link tags to the document
        jsFiles.forEach(jsFile => {
          if (jsFile.includes("runtime")) {
            return;
          }
          const script = document.createElement('script');
          const source = jsFile.split("/").pop();
          script.src = `${fetchurl}/${source}`;
          script.type= "module";
          document.body.append(script);
        });

        cssFiles.forEach(cssFile => {
          const link = document.createElement('link');
          link.rel = 'stylesheet';
          const source = cssFile.split("/").pop();
          link.href = `${fetchurl}/${source}`;
          document.head.append(link);
        });

        // @ts-ignore
        await renderApp(aws_cf_cd_version);
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchApp("2.1.2");
  }, [version]);
```

This throws an error saying `(0, o.jsx) is not a function` basically the root.render fails cos i can see the `alert` "root created" in the first app while serving it.

ReactDom is being imported like this
`import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';`

Need some help in figuring this out

I have tried imorting the ReactDom in different ways. The exports were kept same in both the apps
`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`
`import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'`
`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'`

as these were some of the suggested methods. All these have the same output.

I am expecting the `root.render` to work fine in the app1, I do not want to install app2 as a seperate package, Trying to render different version of the app based on headers being passed.

Comment: Just curious... but why? This seems so complicated compared to just serving different versions of the app on different routes.

Comment: The url will be the same, based on the headers a different version of the app will be rendered. Some users will be directed to the new version of the app and  the rest to the older version

Comment: So redirecting to different routes based on the headers would be the natural approach. Why do you want/need to do this instead?

Comment: I will try to explain with the best of my knowledge, I am new to this. 
The url will not be the same right? i want the user to be on xyz.com, lets say there are 10 users, I want 2 users to see a different version of the app and the remaining to see the same version. If there is a cleaner and simpler way please let me know or point me to some docs. Thanks in advance

Comment: What I would do is if a user goes to `xyz.com`, they would get redirected to `xyz.com/v1` or `/v2` depending on the header. Or you can do the same thing but with `v1.xyz.com` and `v2.xyz.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. This method will not be of use cos the url cannot be modified in any way, The url used is based of on some settings that is generated based on tenants.